# Is there an Ubuntu theme to make it look like OS X?

Tags: themes, macosx

Is there any theme available for Ubuntu that will make it look similar to Mac OS X ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a video on making Ubuntu 11.04 look like Snow Leopard: http://youtu.be/pKu6mM9XqNc

Final image from the video:

[image]

Things used:

- [Modified Mac4Lin theme](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6864546/Mac4Lin_modified_theme.tar.gz) Install with `appearance`.
- [Mac4Lin icon set](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6864546/Mac4Lin_Icons_modified.tar.gz) Doubleclick file to install. In `appearance` choose ‘customize’ and choose Mac4Lin_GTK_v0.4.
- [Mac4Lin wallpaper](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mac4lin/Mac4Lin_Wallpapers_Part3_v0.4.tar.gz?modtime=1198007584&big_mirror=0&filesize=12555519) Rightclick desktop, change wallpaper.
- [Avant Windows Manager elegant glass theme](http://gnome-look.org/CONTENT/content-files/66381-Elegant_glass.tgz) See: http://maketecheasier.com/turn-your-ubuntu-hardy-to-mac-osx-leopard/2008/07/23

Works for all `classic` versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I use [graphite](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Elementary+Graphite?content=136045&PHPSESSID=d29d4d213f340e6c6bef1f85650606ec) as my theme for the window borders so they look like the old green, yellow, red buttons from leopard.